# Error when submitting a form with PrimeFaces without using Ajax

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am working on a JavaWeb project using Jakarta Server Faces and PrimeFaces 12. I am trying to process a form that has 4 SelectOneMenu that update each other (the selected element of the first updates the elements available in the second, the selected element of the second updates those of the third and so on). I have used Ajax so that changing the state of any of these selectOneMenu updates the values of the remaining selectOneMenu.

The submit button of the form processes the entire form, but I need it not to use Ajax to process the form because this button also downloads a report resulting from the values selected in the selectOneMenu.

If I put the code ajax = true to the submit button of the form, it processes but the file is not downloaded, however, if I disable Ajax to the button, even though valid values have been selected in all the selectOneMenu, they throw an error indicating that the values are invalid and the form is not completed.

I present the code I am using:

```html
            #{reportsBean.update_Area()}
            <h:form id="form1">
                <p:growl id="messages" allowDismiss="true"/>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col col-sm-6">
                        <p:outputLabel for="areaInput"
                                       styleClass="block"> &Aacute;rea </p:outputLabel> <br/>
                        <p:selectOneMenu value="#{reportsBean.area}"
                                         id="areaInput"
                                         requiredMessage="&Aacute;rea: Es necesario seleccionar una Facultad"
                                         required="true" label="&Aacute;rea">
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="(Seleccione un &Aacute;rea)" itemValue=""/>
                            <f:selectItems value="#{reportsBean.list_area}" var="a" itemValue="#{a}"
                                           itemLabel="#{a}"/>
                            <p:ajax update="carrera plan_estudio asignatura"/>
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col col-sm-6">
                        <p:outputPanel id="carrera">
                            #{reportsBean.updtate_carrera()}
                            <p:outputLabel for="carreraInput"
                                           styleClass="block"> Carrera </p:outputLabel> <br/>
                            <p:selectOneMenu value="#{reportsBean.carrera}"
                                             id="carreraInput"
                                             requiredMessage="Carrera: Es necesario seleccionar una Carrera"
                                             required="true" label="Carrera">
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="(Seleccione una Carrera)" itemValue=""/>
                                <f:selectItems value="#{reportsBean.list_carrera}" var="c" itemValue="#{c}"
                                               itemLabel="#{c}"/>
                                <p:ajax update="plan_estudio asignatura"/>
                            </p:selectOneMenu>
                        </p:outputPanel>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br/>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col col-sm-6">
                        <p:outputPanel id="plan_estudio">
                            #{reportsBean.update_plan_estudio()}
                            <p:outputLabel for="planEstudioInput"
                                           styleClass="block"> Plan de Estudio </p:outputLabel> <br/>
                            <p:selectOneMenu id="planEstudioInput" value="#{reportsBean.plan_estudio}"
                                             requiredMessage="Plan de Estudio: Es necesario seleccionar un Plan de Estudio"
                                             required="true" label="Plan de Estudio">
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="(Seleccione un Plan de Estudio)" itemValue=""/>
                                <f:selectItems value="#{reportsBean.list_plan_estudio}" var="pe" itemValue="#{pe}"
                                               itemLabel="#{pe}"/>
                                <p:ajax update="asignatura"/>
                            </p:selectOneMenu>
                        </p:outputPanel>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col col-sm-6">
                        <p:outputPanel id="asignatura">
                            <p:outputLabel for="asignaturaInput"
                                           styleClass="block"> Asignatura </p:outputLabel> <br/>
                            #{reportsBean.update_Asignaturas()}
                            <p:selectOneMenu value="#{reportsBean.asignatura_Ms13d}"
                                             id="asignaturaInput"
                                             requiredMessage="Asignatura: Es necesario seleccionar una Asignatura"
                                             required="true" label="Asignatura">
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="(Seleccione una Asignatura)" itemValue=""/>
                                <f:selectItems value="#{reportsBean.list_asignatura}" var="pe" itemValue="#{pe}"
                                               itemLabel="#{pe}"/>
                            </p:selectOneMenu>
                        </p:outputPanel>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br/>

                <div style="float: right">
                    <p:commandButton title="PDF" style="margin-right: 10px" icon="pi pi-file-pdf"
                                     styleClass="ui-button ui-button-secondary" ajax="false"
                                     actionListener="#{reportsBean.print_rs4b_tipo1_PDF()}">
                    </p:commandButton>
                    <p:commandButton title="DOC" style="margin-right: 10px" icon="pi pi-file-word"
                                     styleClass="ui-button ui-button-secondary" ajax="false"
                                     actionListener="#{reportsBean.print_rs4b_tipo1_DOC()}">
                    </p:commandButton>
                    <p:commandButton title="RTF" style="margin-right: 10px" icon="pi pi-file"
                                     styleClass="ui-button ui-button-secondary" ajax="false"
                                     actionListener="#{reportsBean.print_rs4b_tipo1_RTF()}">
                    </p:commandButton>
                </div>

                <input type="hidden"
                       name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
                       value="${_csrf.token}"/>
            </h:form>
```

This is an image of the form that once filled out, the generate PDF button was pressed, the form values were deleted and the error messages for each of the selectOneMenu were displayed.

[image: Mensaje de error que se muestra la procesar el formulario]

I hope you can help me solve this problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: I didn't look into this that deeply, but know that you can use Ajax downloading from PF10. https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/download.xhtml

Comment: Thanks @JasperdeVries for your response. The function that calls the button is responsible for processing and downloading a report made with Jasper Reports, using the information from the selectOneMenu.
When you enable ajax on the button, the form is processed correctly, but the report is not downloaded. However, when disabling ajax, the report is downloaded correctly but when the selectOneMenu are included in the form, they prevent the form from being sent, and therefore the report is not downloaded.

Comment: Please read https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/12_0_0/#/components/filedownload

Comment: Thanks @JasperdeVries. I have been reviewing the link you gave me and with a refactoring of the code I have managed to generate the report and allow me to download it, all using Ajax. I'll create an answer to explain the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Jasper de Vries for his responses in the comment. Here, I give you the complete solution.

To resolve this situation, ajax can be used. The Download component of primefaces can be used. Using the Primefaces `StreamedContent` class, the stream of the generated report can be obtained and later sent to the view through `p:filedownloader`.

The view would look like this:

```
<h:form id="form1">
                <p:growl id="messages" allowDismiss="true"/>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col col-sm-3">
                        <p:outputLabel for="idSearch"
                                       styleClass="block"> Identificaci&oacute;n </p:outputLabel>
                        <p:inputMask
                                id="idSearch"
                                mask="99999999999"
                                requiredMessage="ERROR: Es necesario un valor para establecer la b&uacute;squeda"
                                validatorMessage="ERROR: Idemtificaci&oacute;n no v&aacute;lida"
                                placeholder="Identificaci&oacute;n" value="#{reportsBean.idEstudiante}"
                                required="true"
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <br/>
                        <p:commandButton title="PDF" style="margin-right: 10px" icon="pi pi-file-pdf"
                                         styleClass="ui-button ui-button-secondary" ajax="true" update="form1"
                                         actionListener="#{reportsBean.printCertCalifCursoAc('PDF')}">
                            <p:fileDownload value="#{reportsBean.file}"/>
                        </p:commandButton>
                        <p:commandButton title="DOCX" style="margin-right: 10px" icon="pi pi-file-word"
                                         styleClass="ui-button ui-button-secondary" ajax="true" update="form1"
                                         actionListener="#{reportsBean.printCertCalifCursoAc('DOCX')}">
                            <p:fileDownload value="#{reportsBean.file}"/>
                        </p:commandButton>
                        <p:commandButton title="RTF" style="margin-right: 10px" icon="pi pi-file"
                                         styleClass="ui-button ui-button-secondary" ajax="true" update="form1"
                                         actionListener="#{reportsBean.printCertCalifCursoAc('RTF')}">
                            <p:fileDownload value="#{reportsBean.file}"/>
                        </p:commandButton>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden"
                       name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
                       value="${_csrf.token}"/>
            </h:form>
```

Then, in the bean, the bases are prepared to process the file, the `StreamedContent` object is defined and with a function the report data is sent to the report processor.

```
public void printCertCalifCursoAc(String type){
        Map<String, Object> params = new java.util.HashMap<String, Object>();
        params.put("id", idEstudiante);
        String fileName = "Certificado de Calificaciones de Curso Académico - " + idEstudiante + "." + type.toLowerCase();
        String jasperPath = URL + "ms19d.jasper";
        FileType fileType = FileType.valueOf(type);
        try {
            file = reportUtil.processReport(params, jasperPath, fileName, fileType);
        } catch (JRException | IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

Finally, the file is processed, taking into account the type of file to be processed (PDF, RTF or DOCX in this case). And the `StreamContent` is sent to the Bean and then sent to the view.

```
private StreamedContent getStreamedcontent(ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream, String fileName) throws IOException {
        InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray());
        SerializableSupplier<InputStream> supplier = () -> inputStream;
        StreamedContent streamedContent = DefaultStreamedContent.builder()
                .contentType("application/octet-stream")
                .name(fileName)
                .stream(supplier)
                .build();
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        inputStream.close();
        return streamedContent;
    }

    public StreamedContent processReport(Map<String, Object> params, String jasperpath, String fileName, FileType fileType) throws IOException, JRException {
        if (params == null) {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "ERROR: Debe seleccionar o introducir un valor", "Error"));
        }
        String relativeWebPath = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRealPath(jasperpath);
        File file = new File(relativeWebPath);
        Connection con = connection.getConnectionInstance("org.postgresql.Driver", "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/SIGENU_EaD", "postgres", "postgres");
        String filename = file.getPath();
        JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(filename, params, con);
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        switch (fileType) {
            case PDF -> JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(print, outputStream);
            case RTF -> {
                JRRtfExporter exporter = new JRRtfExporter();
                exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, print);
                exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, outputStream);
                exporter.exportReport();
            }
            case DOCX -> {
                JRDocxExporter exporter = new JRDocxExporter();
                exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, print);
                exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, outputStream);
                exporter.exportReport();
            }
        }
        return getStreamedcontent(outputStream, fileName);
    }
```